# Accessing DynamoDB from IOS SDK on AWS with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have used Lamdba and set up IAM and Cognito and got a identityId and token.  I am confused on the next steps. The user is authenticated in Cognito after login. But how do I keep them logged in like by refreshing the token when the app loads? And how do I query DynamoDB using only authenticated users? The documentation is vague. Also using Federated identities and my own OpenID developer authentication process written in lambda.

Comment: take a look at this sample https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/developer-authenticated-identities-2-4/CognitoSync-Sample/Objective-C